# View Content of text file hosted on webserver in txt format

Tags: http, view, text-files

Recently i uploaded a text file on free hosting. consider name of txt file = lml.txt and the domain = asd.net. While opening it from browser like = http://asd.net/lml.txt - it ends up showing a blank screen. The location of lml.txt is in / directory and it contains some lines too (lml.txt). Using ftp i can access but i cant by using http. Is there any way to read the contents present in it ?

Comment: This question is way to broad and the issue could be caused by many things, like webserver configuration and/or file access permissions. It's hardly related to programming.

Comment: Flagged as too broad.  @Rahul consider contacting support from your hosting provider, this issue is not programming related but rather seems to be an issue u[loading files to your web host.  Good luck!